# How to change the spacing between shapes in a pattern brush in Illustrator

Tags: brush

I'm trying to create a hair braid pattern on a circle and somehow can't seem to change the spacing between the shapes in the brush. I want to close the gaps. I'm working in Ai CS6.

Comment: Picture tells a thousand words here.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit cryptic (you should make it better even if this answers your question). But here is by guess of what your asking:

Your trying to do a semless pattern brush but your experiencing that the pattern does not repeat properly. That is because the pattern is taken from the bounding box of your graphics.

[image: gap]

**Image 1**: there is small but noticable gap where the patterns meet

While you would like to have no gap

[image: no gap]

**Image 2**: There is no visible gap where patterns meet.

You do this by placing a no stroke no fill rectangle behind your graphic before you make it into a pattern.

[image: bounding box]

**Image 3**: Make a non stroking non filling box behind to bound what gets drawn out of the pattern.